# Use a context manager to redirect script output to a file?

Tags: python, file-io, contextmanager

I'm programming a script where I have an option, to be passed on the command line, whether the script should print its results to stdout or to a predefined results file. A code outline for this is shown below. I now have read a little bit about context managers in Python, but am not really sure whether and how to use a context manager in this specific situation. So I am looking for advice

1. whether it makes sense to use a context manager in this problem
2. how to go about implementing it.

So, the code without context manager is:

```
option_file = True # would come from OptionParser in real code

if option_file:
    out = open("resultsfile", "w")
else:
    out = sys.stdout

# do some computations
out.write("Results of script")
# more computations and calls to out.write

if option_file:
    out.close()
```

Comment: [`contextlib.redirect_stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout) was added to Python 3.4 in 2014 to do this kind of thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A context manager is something you can use with a `with` statement. It is explicitly designed to:

- perform some setup,
- give you an object, and
- perform some teardown again (even if you raise an exception).

For example, `open` can be used as a context manager. In the following code

```
with open(...) as f:
    # do stuff
```

it doesn't matter what `stuff` is, the file will always be closed. (Well, usually. Except in silly cases like the power being turned off or the process being killed.)

You should use a context manager when you are in this sort of situation. It doesn't look to me like you are, so I see no reason for a context manager.

---

There is an alternative (not better or worse, just different) way of writing your code that does use a context manager. If you want to redirect `stdout` temporarily -- but ensure that you restore it when you're done -- then you are in the situation above. Here's an example:

```
@contextlib.contextmanager
def redirect_stdout(stream):
    import sys
    sys.stdout = stream
    yield
    sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
```

You can then write code like

```
with open(...) as f:
    with redirect_stdout(f):
        # do stuff
```

and any writes to stdout in `stuff` will go to `f` instead.

---

EDIT: You are correct that there is no way conditionally to have a context manager: either you are in one or you aren't. You could always write your own which might do nothing:

```
@contextlib.contextmanager
def maybe_open(path, do_nothing=True):
    if do_nothing:
        f = None
        yield sys.stdout
    else:
        f = open(path)
        yield f

    if f:
        f.close()
```

This is almost certainly overkill.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So when the script may through an exception between the file opening and closing statements, a context manager would make sense? I just have no idea how to implement **conditional use** of the context manager (depending on the option whether to write to stdout or to the file).

Comment: BTW, I cannot redirect stdout in this situation, because some output of the script should still go to stdout, and not the results file.

Comment: @silvado: you are correct that you can't conditionally have a `with` statement in your code -- either it's there or it's not. Your original solution (conditionally set `out` to be something and then write everything to `out`) is good. Another way would be to wrap everything in a context manager but have that context manager do nothing conditionally. Will edit to explain.

Comment: @silvado: Also note that closing files in Python isn't very important, because they'll be closed when they're garbage collected anyway. Explicitly closing them (either with `.close()` or with `with`) is good practice, but not necessary.